# Photoshop CS5: How can I change the default reference point location?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When adjusting a selection in photoshop, the reference point is always set to the center:

[image: reference point location]

Regardless what I change it to, the next selection will always reset it to the center. Is there any way to set it to the top most left corner by default, so that every new selection starts with the reference point set there?

Edit: I don't think this makes any difference, but just in case, I use CS5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to have the 9 point origin show anything but the center point as the default. There's certainly no setting anywhere in the application to alter it that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I always want to set the Reference Point to the top left as default since an odd pixel Object will create "half-pixels". Sadly, there is no way to set it as default, and this problem exists all the way through to CS6.

One possible workaround that I have used in the past is to do a Recorded Action of a transformation. However, this only works on specific objects and with specific transformations. You can't simply play an Action of just setting the reference point to the top left either since Actions won't remain in a mode unless it's confirmed. And of course once you confirm a transformation the Layer Reference Point is reset to the default center.

Edit: Grammar.